# Elements from first row of table in db return: column name and two dashes aswell as its value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, powershell

I am using powershell to store and get data from database.

I am having problems getting weird data from the first row of the tables.
It looks like this
[image]

This is my powershell script.

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance 'localhost' -inputfile 
C:\Users\Matej\Desktop\SQLQuery2.sql

function insertToDb($line, $PlaylistId){

$position = $line.ToString().Split(',').Get(0)
$songName = $line.ToString().Split(',').Get(1)
$artistName = $line.ToString().Split(',').Get(2)
$link = $line.ToString().Split(',').Get(4)
Write-Output 'PlaylistId: '$PlaylistId


$insertSongQuery = "
    INSERT INTO SONG
        (position,name,artist,link,playlist_id)
    VALUES
        ('$position','$songName','$artistName','$link','$PlaylistId')
    GO
"
#Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'localhost' -query $insertSongQuery -U vikiUser - 
 Password 1234 -Database ProjectDb
 }

function getPlaylist{
$shortName = $PSItem.ToString().Split(',').Get(0);
$name = $PSItem.ToString().Split(',').Get(1);
$insertquery = "
 INSERT INTO PLAYLIST
       (name, type) 
 VALUES 
       ('$name','country') 
 GO 
"
$getPlaylistIdQuery = "
    SELECT ID
    FROM PLAYLIST 
    WHERE PLAYLIST.name = '$name'
    GO
"
Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'localhost' -query $insertquery -U vikiUser -Password 1234 -Database ProjectDb 
$PlaylistId= Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'localhost' -query $getPlaylistIdQuery -U vikiUser -Password 1234 -Database ProjectDb


(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://spotifycharts.com/regional/$shortName/daily/latest/download).Content > out.csv
cat out.csv | Select-Object -skip 2 | select -First 10 | ForEach-Object {insertToDb $_ $PlaylistId}

#get 10
#insert Song(position,name,artist,playlist id)
}


cat C:\Users\Matej\Desktop\countries.txt | ForEach-Object {getPlaylist($_)}
```

What my thought is that it gets the database as a format of columns and rows, and above the first row, and between the columns there are lines which align the looks of the database, that is why i'm getting the name of the first row aswell as the value. How could i go past this?
I tried assinging a global 'flag' variable and setting the first value to 0, and the others to their normal values, but i cannot edit global values in powershell(I guess).
What should i do?

Comment: that is - usually - the PoSh display system. what is in the `$PlaylistId` variable at the point that you get that display? try `$PlaylistId | Get-Member`, or `$PlaylistId | Select-Object -Property *`, or `$PlaylistId.GetType()`.

Comment: Why aren't you simply using [`ConverFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lee points out, this is not an error, this is the default from tabular data that has headers. All DB's do. If you don't want the header, dot reference the data value. Since you are not showing any sample data, expected input/output.

So, something like this...

```
cat out.csv | 
Select-Object -First 10 | 
ForEach-Object {insertToDb $PSItem.playlist_id}
```